# No input signal on monitor, connection through display port, no os installed

Tags: linux, boot, vga, displayport

My hardware is i7 6700 with Intel HD graphics, Nvidia Quadro k620. The computer has two display ports and one DVI port which is on the Quadro card. At the moment there is no OS installed since I asked for an empty system on which I'm going to install Linux. But my problem is the monitor is not getting any input signal. When I boot up the computer boots, but I can't enter the bios as the monitor says no signal and goes to sleep. The connection is over a display port to display port cable.

Any ideas why this is happening, is it because there is no OS installed so there won't be any drivers either? Would a VGA connection work and then after I install the OS I can switch to display port? But if the first boot has to be in VGA how would that work because the computer does not have a VGA port, but the monitor has one so even if I use a VGA to display port adapter, the output from the computer won't be VGA?

I'm quite confused about this...if anyone can help me it would be awesome..
Thanks
Kabir

Comment: You've only provided information on the CPU and GPUs.  The missing and salient information is the motherboard.  The BIOS/UEFI will probably default to one video/display port.  Check your mobo manual.  IOW RTM.

Comment: Drivers are not needed. If the display port is the primary display then it shoudl work. However you seem to have two display outs. If the VGA out on the intel HD graphics is active as primary then the Nvidia DP out will be blank.

Comment: @Hennes, sawdust thanks for your comments, both the display ports are on the Intel HD graphics. The computer has no VGA port. I only tried one of the two display ports, thinking either should work, it didn't strike me that only one of the two could work. I will try the other port. Also, I will look for a mobo manual online, they didn't give one with the system.

Comment: Who is *"they"*?  If *"they"* actually configured the system prior to shipping (rather than just slap parts together), then the NVIDIA GPU was probably configured as primary, so the DVI connector is likely to be live.

Comment: @sawdust yeah you're right only Nvidia works and takes me to free dos, "they" is HP. I thought the display ports should work out of the box, anyway at least now I can install an OS. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience most BIOS/UEFI are configured such that if a GPU is the slot it becomes primary and the Intel HD becomes disabled. The OS can go back and enable it later and some UEFI even are intelligent enough to mirror both.

A DVI connector is actually two separate interfaces. One is called DVI-D and the other are pins capable with VGA so with a passive adapter you can break out a VGA connector. You probably have one of these laying around so try to find one or maybe youd rather buy one?

If not that your next course of action is to simply unplug your graphics card which will make the UEFI enable the Intel HD graphics.

Mind you Linux installers should enable both monitors and mirror them. You might wanna try that to.

Comment: thanks, yeah the GPU was the only live port and next to the DVI port it has a display port, so I made the connection through that and it worked.